# How to calculate the sample size for a 2-sided t test?

Tags: r, python, t-test, statistical-power, two-tailed-test

I want to calculate the sample size $n$ for a two-sided t-test with the following values:

- alpha = 0.05
- power = 0.8
- effect size = 0.8

This is the code I tried in Python:

```
n = statsmodels.stats.power.tt_ind_solve_power(effect_size=0.8, alpha=0.05, power=0.8)
print(n)
```

This is the code I tried in R:

```
result = power.t.test(sig.level=0.05, delta=0.8, power=0.8)
print(result["n"])
```

The result is 25.524. But I noticed this program is not the same:

```
from scipy.stats import norm

def calculate_n(alpha, power, effect_size):
    t_alpha = norm.ppf(alpha / 2)
    t_beta = norm.ppf(1 - power)

    return 2 * ((t_alpha + t_beta) / effect_size)**2

n = calculate_n(alpha=0.05, power=0.8, effect_size=0.8)
print(n)
```

The result is 24.527. How to calculate sample size? I want to know the formula.

(postscript)

I tried this code, but power is wrong.

```
import scipy.stats as stats

def test_n(alpha, effect_size, n):
    t_alpha = stats.t.ppf(1 - alpha / 2, df=n-1)

    # chones'd = effect_size = (mean1 - mean2) / s
    # if std1 and std2 are 1, s is always 1.
    # s = np.sqrt(((n1 - 1) * std1**2 + (n2 - 1) * std2**2) / ((n1 - 1) + (n2 - 1)))
    power = stats.t.cdf(t_alpha, loc=effect_size, df=n-1)
    
    return power 

for n in range(2, 50):

    power = test_n(alpha=0.05, effect_size=0.8, n=n)
    print(power)
```

Comment: Welcome to CV! There is more than one formula, depending on precisely which t-test you plan to apply and how fussy you are about getting really precise estimates of sample size, given that such calculations are made by making so many guesses that precision is beside the point.

Comment: Briefly, I agree with the points in what whuber wrote, but I'd have expected the power function to use the *noncentral* t in the tbeta part, which the python function doesn't seem to do. But maybe I'm missing something

Comment: thank you for your comment. I tried scipy.stats.t.ppf.